# HttpPostedFileBase.ContentLength.ToString() retorna "0"

Tags: c#

Segue código:

```
HttpFileCollectionBase files;
```

Eu pego o tamanho do arquivo assim:

```
var tamanho = files[0].ContentLength; //tamanho é 1250
```

Até agora funciona normal, quando quero converter para string:

```
var tamanho = files[0].ContentLength.ToString(); //para string "0"
```

Com `ToString()` retorna `"0"`. Porque isso acontece ?

**Update:**

O código a seguir funciona:

```
var tamanho = files[0].ContentLength;
var tamanho_string = tamanho.ToString(); //funciona "1250"
```

Quando eu faço `ToString()` direto, ex:

```
var tamanho = files[0].ContentLength.ToString(); // "0"
```

Comment: você está declarando o file como está na pergunta ou está atribuindo um valor para ele? Ex:  `HttpFileCollection files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;`

Comment: @LeandroAngelo atribuindo um valor para ele